# CloudFlare Scrape 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting a "403 forbidden" error when trying to send a post request to https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/orders/populate.json in order to add to cart the item on the following page: https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001.

Here is my code:

```
import cfscrape
scrape = cfscrape.create_scraper()
payload = {"variant_id": "107917", "quantity": "1"}
headers={
    "accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-length": "35",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "refer": "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001",
    "origin":"https://www.off---white.com",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

res = scrape.post("https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/orders/populate.json",headers=headers,data=payload)
print(res.status_code)  #=403 :(
```

Thank you.

EDIT: Apparently i need cookies. I changed the code as follows, but i'm still getting 403 forbidden.

```
cookie, user_agent=scrape.get_cookie_string("https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001")
headers={
    "authority":"www.off---white.com",
    "accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-length": "35",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "refer": "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001",
    "origin":"https://www.off---white.com",
    "cookie": cookie,
    "user-agent": user_agent,
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
res = scrape.post("https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/orders/populate.json",headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Some tips on what is still missing?

EDIT2: I've also tried the following:

```
tokens, user_agent=scrape.get_tokens("https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001")
headers={
    "authority":"www.off---white.com",
    "accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-length": "35",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "refer": "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001",
    "origin":"https://www.off---white.com",
    "user-agent": user_agent,
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
res = scrape.post("https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/orders/populate.json",headers=headers,data=payload,cookies=tokens)
```

Again, no luck. Also, regardless of how I submit cookies I noticed that whenever I have them the request is rejected immediately, cfscrape's node.js window doesn't even open up.

Comment: This is exactly what CloudFlare is supposed to prevent. You're out of luck here.

Comment: Currently there are bots working on the website, so I guess CloudFlare is not doing a good job

Comment: Use selenium to run a headless chrome browser... I've used cfscrape in the past without issues.

Comment: Seems like [cfscrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) would be who to turn to, given they acknowledge "Cloudflare changes their techniques periodically, so I will update this repo frequently."

Comment: I'm already using cloudflarescrape, that's the issue.

Comment: And it works flawlessly for GET requests

Comment: the reason why you got `403` is you dont have any right to access it. btw GET is not available , i got `403` too

Comment: I meant that using cfscrape to perform GET requests on the website always worked like a charm. But I have something in mind to test now, maybe I should try to open a requests session, then GET the product page first and finally perform the POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Content-Length is correct? That could be one issue. Usually you don't need to include this and it gets added on by itself later. The other issue is most likely cookies. I don't see you sending cookies back with your POST request. There are 2 required cookies, one is _hs_session_v3 that you are not sending.

EDIT: 
Do this in your browser: 1. GET request to off---white.com. save all those cookies. 2. GET request from off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/…. save those cookies. 3. POST request will work. To test this, do this: Clear all your browser cache/cookies. Go to off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/…, it doesn't even load the page.. why not? Your cookies are not set. The site is using your cookies to determine whether your request is valid. You are requesting a page which relies on cookie for valid response.

When I click, add to bag, this is the curl: curl 'https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/orders/populate.json' -H 'cookie: __cfduid=db351a20a2752d5459220f241c66440371539900632; dismiss_cookie_law=true; guest_token=Im41TjNZWFBFRFFwaUdvNkpTeVJDZnci--1fca5ea27af50cba12cd96f088975f5f5e0647ac; __riskifiedBeaconSessionId=c0f01056-f52a4b5a-76f25d73-cdb11d12-c2f20dbc-8173a1e0; cf_clearance=eb87f25251aeab5062f65bc7a5261b9cbef35809-1539947407-1800-150; _hs_session_v3=UHRUWUtUVDJKTTExeEkxTVNQVlFMSVQySUR1VXlZZFJGaGZJck0zOTBPbVZSWjUvL01pR2J1UktjOXFPMTZiK2pVbm5jVGtkUU9GRVpJVGR0VWkxZGUyWGNvak5kZXllR2tEMG5yOERHMmVMaHJxaUxYRHRGVUp3NXAvZERGSm9nREZBc0Z0bDJsM241VHhzdU16S05WT3BUaFlNbVhwYkd3cGNjdHAzSHpRPS0tZ2pOR25tNzJMTWlTY3U1MDJTaW9iQT09--44bbe09a45974b9e7584588b186650946c1b6f73' -H 'origin: https://www.off---white.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'authority: www.off---white.com' -H 'referer: https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/women/products/owea143e18a640731001' -H 'dnt: 1' --data-binary '{"variant_id":null, "quantity":1}' --compressed

Comment: Yeah, content-length is correct, that's the same value that gets passed on my browser. I have no idea what values to pass as cookies though.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I edited my code and added cookies. Still getting 403 though, I don't understand why but my cookies have the __cfduid parameter and the cf_clearance parameter, but no _hs_session_v3 gets retrieved.

Comment: I've edited my code again, but still no luck. I cannot find the _hs_session_v3 cookie.